# Making a UIView keep its size when used as a table header view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

If I use the following code to add a `tableHeaderView` to a table...

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
label.text = @"Hello, world!";
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = label;
```

The result is that the content of the table is pushed down by the height of the label.

This is fine and is what I want.

However, when I use my own custom view (set up in code) which has its own subviews etc... then the content of the table is not pushed down and the header view overlaps onto the content.

I'm not using AutoLayout to place the subviews of my custom view because of the nature of the view it doesn't really work as an AutoLayout view.

The frame of my custom view is `(0, 0, 0, 0)` with the content of the header view being drawn outside its bounds.

I have implemented the `- (CGSize)sizeThatFitsSize:(CGSize)size` method of my custom view but that hasn't changed anything.

Is there something else I need to implement also?

**Example**

If I use the following code to put a label inside my custom view...

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
        label.text = @"Hello, world!";
        [label sizeToFit];
        [self addSubview:label];

        label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(label.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(label.bounds));
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then the label appears in the same place as before but the content is not pushed down.

Comment: Why do you have the custom view frame 0 ?  I have a custom view with some labels in it, and I used it as headerview and it did push the table content down, and it didnt overlap the table content.

Comment: @Mr.T if I knew that then I wouldn't have to ask the question  what I'd like to know is how to get my view to set its frame properly based on its contents (without using AutoLayout). It seems to resize itself to (0, 0, 0, 0) whenever the system updates its layout.

Comment: @Mr.T see my edit. Thanks

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @Suragch i ended up making a self sizing cell and using that instead or a header.

Comment: @Suragch there are thousands of questions about self sizing cells. The Apple documentation even covers them.

Answer (score 2):

The frame of the view when you set it as the table header view is the size that the table view allocates and maintains for the view.

So, you need to determine the required size for your header view and change it's frame before setting it.

The table view will not make and queries or size changes for you. Autoresizing rules do apply so if the table view frame changes the header view will be resized according to the rules you specify. This may lead to different issues.